# xercesc is not parsing chinese characters properly and creating xml tag without proper end tag

Tags: xerces-c

The input string contains "CDR   2324-5  No Compatibilit頩nt. nж06....tri饠par prodkjdl".

The expected xml is :

> ```
> <param>
> <name>comments</name>
> <value>CDR   2324-5  No Compatibilit頩nt. nж06....tri饠par prodkjdl</value>
> </param>
> ```

I am using following function to insert the string into the xml.

```
 DOM_Text newNode = document.createTextNode("");
 newNode.setNodeValue( (const sChar*) value );
 element.appendChild( newNode );
```

Where the 'value' is "CDR   2324-5  No Compatibilit頩nt. nж06....tri饠par prodkjdl ".

The XML is got generated **but without the of end of tag**.  I got following error message,

> **Error: The input ended before all started tags were ended. Last tag
>   started was 'param'.**

**If i remove those 3 Chinese characters, then everything working fine.**

I am using Linux RHEL 62.
xercesc version taken from XercesVersion.hpp is,

```
XERCES_VERSION_MAJOR 2
XERCES_VERSION_MINOR 5
```

Same thing working fine in windows machine.
i suspect that, i may use some deprecated version or function. but i am not sure.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by converting the value into DOMString instead of SChar*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed, the sChar* was not able to handle the Chinese characters. I have converted the string into DOMString. now everything works fine.

```
DOMString val = DOMString( value.c_str() );
DOM_Text newNode = document.createTextNode("");
newNode.setNodeValue( val );
element.appendChild( newNode );
```

Now i am seeing proper end of tag .